# Equivalent of cW to change backward

Tags: vim

I usually use `cW` to remove the text from the cursor is till the next space, but how to do the same removing till the space before, that is backward.

Comment: Vim has many motions (and great documentation too!). You can be read all about the various motions via `:h motion.txt`. If you need a more concise list then use the quickref, `:h quickref`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The opposite of `w` is the `b` ("backwards") motion. Likewise for WORD motions: `W` and `B`. So, if I understand you correctly, `cB` should do that.